# Changing version number to single digits python

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-3.x, tuples

I have a version number in a file like this:

> Testing x.x.x.x

So I am grabbing it off like this:

```
import re

def increment(match):
    # convert the four matches to integers
    a,b,c,d = [int(x) for x in match.groups()]
    # return the replacement string
    return f'{a}.{b}.{c}.{d}'

lines = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
lines[3] = re.sub(r"\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\b", increment, lines[3])
```

I want to make it so if the last digit is a `9`... then change it to `0` and then change the previous digit to a 1. So `1.1.1.9` changes to `1.1.2.0`.

I did that by doing:

```
def increment(match):
    # convert the four matches to integers
    a,b,c,d = [int(x) for x in match.groups()]
    # return the replacement string
    if (d == 9):
        return f'{a}.{b}.{c+1}.{0}'
    elif (c == 9):
        return f'{a}.{b+1}.{0}.{0}'
    elif (b == 9):
        return f'{a+1}.{0}.{0}.{0}'
```

Issue occurs when its `1.1.9.9` or `1.9.9.9`. Where multiple digits need to rounded. How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integer addition?

```
def increment(match):
    # convert the four matches to integers
    a,b,c,d = [int(x) for x in match.groups()]

    *a,b,c,d = [int(x) for x in str(a*1000 + b*100 + c*10 + d + 1)]
    a = ''.join(map(str,a)) # fix for 2 digit 'a'
    # return the replacement string
    return f'{a}.{b}.{c}.{d}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your versions are never going to go beyond 10, it is better to just convert it to an integer, increment it and then convert back to a string.
This allows you to go up to as many version numbers as you require and you are not limited to thousands.

```
def increment(match):
    match = match.replace('.', '')
    match = int(match)
    match += 1
    match = str(match)
    output = '.'.join(match)
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `1` to the last element. If it's more than `9`, set it to `0` and do the same for the previous element. Repeat as necessary:

```
import re

def increment(match):
    # convert the four matches to integers
    g = [int(x) for x in match.groups()]
    # increment, last one first
    pos = len(g)-1
    g[pos] += 1
    while pos > 0:
        if g[pos] > 9:
            g[pos] = 0
            pos -= 1
            g[pos] += 1
        else:
            break
    # return the replacement string
    return '.'.join(str(x) for x in g)

print (re.sub(r"\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\b", increment, '1.8.9.9'))
print (re.sub(r"\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\b", increment, '1.9.9.9'))
print (re.sub(r"\b(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\b", increment, '9.9.9.9'))
```

Result:

```
1.9.0.0
2.0.0.0
10.0.0.0
```